# JQuery Validator style is mysteriously overriden by CSS stylesheet

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I've been trying to get the Jquery Validator plugin to show error messages in red and a red border when there's an error, but for some reason the CSS style sheet causes the following issues:

**1.** Overrides the red text and the red border errorclass and makes them default color.

**2.** Pushes Errormessage leaving a big ugly space in between the errormessage and the text field.

**3.** Errormessage doesn't dissapear when re-typing on the erroneous text field, and the text inside the field also becomes red.

Here's my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zyv0uLr/  Please, exlplain in the simplest terms possible, I'm an absolute beginner at Jquery and just started learning how to use JQuery validator this week. Thank you!

**CSS:**

```
.error-class{ border-color:2px solid red; color:red;} 

.valid-class{ border-color:2px solid grey; color:black;} 


.user_signup {display: block;}
.user_signup label {display: block; margin-bottom:5px; color:#666;}
.user_signup input[type="text"], .user_signup input[type="email"], .user_signup input[type="password"] {display: block; width:100%; padding:15px; border-radius:5px; border:1.2px solid #DDD; font-size:20px; color:#333; font-family:arial; margin-bottom:20px;    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
}}

.user_signup input[type="password"]:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border-color: #39F;
   }

.user_signup input[type="text"]:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border-color: #39F;
   }

.user_signup input[type="email"]:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border-color: #39F;
   }

.signupbtn { background: #F4F4F2; display:block; width:100%; padding:20px; margin:0px 0; font-size:20px; margin-top:15px; border-radius:5px; box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; color:#FFF; text-align:center; text-decoration:none;background:blue; cursor:pointer; outline:none !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none; border:none;} 

/*.btn_red {background:orange; color: #FFF; }*/

.signupbtn:hover {background:blue; color:white;}



.btnwrapper2 {display:inline-block; width:100%; height:auto; position:relative; clear:both; margin-top:0px; margin-right:10px;
}


.signup-form {text-align:left; float:left; display:inline-block;  }

.signup-form  p {float:left; margin-bottom:15px; font-size:20px; clear:both;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="user_signup" id="user_register1">           
    <form class="signup-form">

    <input class="fullname errorClass" type="text" name="fullname"  placeholder="First and Last Name" />

    <input class="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address"/>

<input class="pass" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="New password" />
            <div class="btnwrapper2">
            <input class="signupbtn" value="Sign up!" type="submit"/> 
          </div>
         </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {



    $.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) { 
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]*$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter only letters"); 

    $.validator.addMethod('strongPassword', function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element)
        || value.length >= 6
        && /\d/.test(value)
        && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
    }, 'Your password is too weak.')

    $(".signup-form").validate({
         errorClass: "error-class",
    validClass: "valid-class",
    rules: {            
             fullname: {
                required: true,
                lettersonly: true
            },

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },

            pass: {
                required: true,
                strongPassword:true
            }
},

messages: {

pass: {
                required: "Please type your new password."          
            },

            email: {
                required: "Please type your username or email.",
                minlength: "Username or email is too short."            
            }
}

}); 
});
```

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin only assigns a CSS class name; it does not contain any styles, sheets, or CSS whatsoever.  If you want the style to display red with a red border, then you have to create these CSS rules and properties yourself.

Comment: There is something in my css preventing the styling, If you erase all the css in my fiddle you will get a red error message, but no red border. So the css is overriding the styles somehow.

Comment: That's impossible.  If you erase all the CSS rules, nothing should be red.  If it is, then you still have CSS from someplace else.

Comment: Yea you're absolutely right, the .error-class{ border-color:2px solid red; color:red;} 
.valid-class{ border-color:2px solid grey; color:black;} are not properly working in the style sheet. Can you figure out what's wrong

Comment: I cleaned it up and found an extra `}` in your CSS.  Otherwise, your CSS rules are wrong.  You cannot assign `2px solid red` to something called `border-color`... those are properties of the whole `border`. `border-color` would simply be a color.  http://jsfiddle.net/5zyv0uLr/2/

Comment: And `.user_signup label` color is overriding your error message `label` color.  You need more specific rules... http://jsfiddle.net/5zyv0uLr/3/

Comment: The input boxes should be red, not the errormessage border. How I can accomplish this? The words also remain black, unless you erase all the other css styles except for error-class. So there must be something wrong there

Comment: I just showed you the core concept.  Simply change it to suit your needs.

Comment: Wow we are almost there. Now how can the input border itself turn red, and why is there a big space betwwen the error message under the text field?

Comment: You should be able to figure out the rest from this:  http://jsfiddle.net/5zyv0uLr/4/

Comment: Thanks Sparky! YOu really helped me understand the problem and here's the solution http://jsfiddle.net/5zyv0uLr/5/ Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

## Why is the border not displayed?

You are using the wrong CSS peropery. It should just be `border`, not `border-color` when you set all the border properties:

```
.error-class{ border: 2px solid red; color: red; }
```

## Why is the color not red?

The value is being overridden by this style rule:

```
.user_signup label {display: block; margin-bottom:5px; color:#666;}
```

Since it is more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), it overrides the less specific rule for `.error-class`. You can fix it by using `!important`:

```
.error-class{ border: 2px solid red; color: red !important; }
```

Using `!important` a lot is generally a bad idea, so instead you could make the selector more specific:

```
.user_signup label.error-class{ border: 2px solid red; color: red !important; }
```

## How do you debug CSS?

Finding out why a CSS rule doesnt stick can be near impossible if you are just reading the code. Instead, use the developer tools in your browser (press F12). This is the information I get in Firefox about the label element you are trying to style when I click it:

[image: Firefox CSS tool]

I can see that the red value for `color` is striked out and not used, and I can see what value is used instead. By unchecking the checkbox I can see what happends if I remove that rule. It makes finding the problem much more easy.

Comment: Thanks for all the useful tips and resources it really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in my original question, my jsfiddle targeted only the border color around the text and not the input fields, but the styles weren't showing up.

> .error-class{ border-color:2px solid red; color:red;}
>
> .valid-class{ border-color:2px solid grey; color:black;}

So in order to tatget the correct elements and make the styles show up I had to first target the input fields:

```
.user_signup input[type="text"].error-class,
.user_signup input[type="email"].error-class,
.user_signup input[type="password"].error-class {
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: red;
}

.user_signup input.valid-class {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    color: black;
}
```

And then target the label fields to change the color of the error-message text to red and moving the text down with a margin-top.

```
.user_signup label.error-class {

    color:red; margin-top:-20px; 
}



.user_signup {
    display: block;
}


.user_signup label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    color:#666;
}
```

Special thanks to Sparky who helped me figure out the answer. Hope this helps someone out there with the same problem as me:

http://jsfiddle.net/5zyv0uLr/5/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="user_signup" id="user_register1">
    <form class="signup-form">
        <input class="fullname errorClass" type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="First and Last Name" />
        <input class="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" />
        <input class="pass" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="New password" />
        <div class="btnwrapper2">
            <input class="signupbtn" value="Sign up!" type="submit" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.user_signup input[type="text"].error-class,
.user_signup input[type="email"].error-class,
.user_signup input[type="password"].error-class {
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: red;
}

.user_signup input.valid-class {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    color: black;
}

.user_signup label.error-class {

    color:red; margin-top:-20px; 
}

.user_signup {
    display: block;
}

.user_signup label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    color:#666;
}

.user_signup input[type="text"], .user_signup input[type="email"], .user_signup input[type="password"] {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    padding:15px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1.2px solid #DDD;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#333;
    font-family:arial;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.user_signup input[type="password"]:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #39F;
}

.user_signup input[type="text"]:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #39F;
}

.user_signup input[type="email"]:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #39F;
}

.signupbtn {
    background: #F4F4F2;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0px 0;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top:15px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:none !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    border:none;
}

/*.btn_red {background:orange; color: #FFF; }*/
 .signupbtn:hover {
    background:blue;
    color:white;
}

.btnwrapper2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.signup-form {
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

.signup-form p {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-size:20px;
    clear:both;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]*$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please enter only letters");

    $.validator.addMethod('strongPassword', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || value.length >= 6 && /\d/.test(value) && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
    }, 'Your password is too weak.')

    $(".signup-form").validate({
        errorClass: "error-class",
        validClass: "valid-class",
        rules: {
            fullname: {
                required: true,
                lettersonly: true
            },

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },

            pass: {
                required: true,
                strongPassword: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            pass: {
                required: "Please type your new password."
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please type your username or email.",
                minlength: "Username or email is too short."
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Perhaps you should include what is different from this version and the original?

Comment: Agree with @Anders.  To best help others, ***explain*** your answer.  Simply dumping a working version of the code is not very useful to others.  Thanks.